# dbus c program - send(with reply) and receive using method_call

Tags: dbus

I'm new to D-Bus. I want a c program to send and receive data using the dbus_message_new_method_call function. I have tried the following programs from the link [How to reply a D-Bus message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19750505/how-to-reply-a-d-bus-message/30914484#30914484)  but I'm getting error in the server.c side like "the name client.signal.Object was not provided by any .service files"

```
"server.c"
/* server.c */

#include <dbus/dbus.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static DBusHandlerResult
filter_func(DBusConnection *connection, DBusMessage *message, void     *usr_data)
{
     DBusMessage *reply;
     dbus_bool_t handled = false;
     char *word = NULL;
     DBusError dberr;
     dbus_error_init(&dberr);
     dbus_message_get_args(message, &dberr, DBUS_TYPE_STRING, &word, DBUS_TYPE_INVALID);
     printf("receive message: %s\n", word);
     handled = true;

     reply = dbus_message_new_method_return(message);
     char * reply_content;
     printf("\nEnter your Reply Msg : ");
     scanf("%s",reply_content);

     dbus_message_append_args(reply, DBUS_TYPE_STRING, &reply_content, DBUS_TYPE_INVALID);

     dbus_connection_send(connection, reply, NULL);
     dbus_connection_flush(connection);
     dbus_message_unref(reply);

 return (handled ? DBUS_HANDLER_RESULT_HANDLED : DBUS_HANDLER_RESULT_NOT_YET_HANDLED);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     DBusError dberr;
     DBusConnection *dbconn;

     dbus_error_init(&dberr);
     dbconn = dbus_bus_get(DBUS_BUS_SESSION, &dberr);

         if (!dbus_connection_add_filter(dbconn, filter_func, NULL, NULL)) 
         {
            return -1;
         }

    dbus_bus_add_match(dbconn, "type='method_call',interface='client.signal.Type'", &dberr);

         while(dbus_connection_read_write_dispatch(dbconn, -1)) 
         {
             /* loop */
         }
 return 0;
}
```

here client.c

```
#include <dbus/dbus.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static DBusHandlerResult
filter_func(DBusConnection *connection, DBusMessage *message, void *usr_data)
{
      dbus_bool_t handled = false;
      char *word = NULL;
      DBusError dberr;

      dbus_error_init(&dberr);
      dbus_message_get_args(message, &dberr, DBUS_TYPE_STRING, &word, DBUS_TYPE_INVALID);

       printf("receive message %s\n", word);
       handled = true;

 return (handled ? DBUS_HANDLER_RESULT_HANDLED : DBUS_HANDLER_RESULT_NOT_YET_HANDLED);
}


int db_send(DBusConnection *dbconn)
{
     DBusMessage *dbmsg;
     char *word = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
     int i;

     dbmsg = dbus_message_new_method_call("client.signal.Object","/client/signal/Object", "client.signal.Type", "Test");

     scanf("%s", word);

         if (!dbus_message_append_args(dbmsg, DBUS_TYPE_STRING, &word, DBUS_TYPE_INVALID)) 
         {
              return -1;
         }

         if (!dbus_connection_send(dbconn, dbmsg, NULL)) 
         {
              return -1;
         }
     dbus_connection_flush(dbconn);
     printf("send message %s\n", word);

     dbus_message_unref(dbmsg);
 return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     DBusError dberr;
     DBusConnection *dbconn;

     dbus_error_init(&dberr);

     dbconn = dbus_bus_get(DBUS_BUS_SESSION, &dberr);
         if (!dbus_connection_add_filter(dbconn, filter_func, NULL, NULL)) 
         {
             return -1;
         }

     db_send(dbconn);

          while(dbus_connection_read_write_dispatch(dbconn, -1)) 
          {
               db_send(dbconn);
          }
     dbus_connection_unref(dbconn);

 return 0;
}
```

Please help me to fix.

Comment: In that case, please use Google and learn the basics. Then learn programming and implement the program on your own. We can help, but we won't do your job.

Comment: If you don't share your error and your source code, how do you expect me to help you?

Comment: Also, please make sure that your spelling and grammar is ok. Reading bad English is exhausting. If people have a hard time understanding you, they won't help you.

Comment: Please edit your code into your question. And before doing so, read that: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask    You won't get any help if you keep posting like that.

Comment: That's a bit better. Now fix your code formatting. Every block between and "{" and an "}" needs to be indented by one level.

Comment: So, finally your question looks like something worth reading. Now please stop being annoying. Do not repeat yourself, do not annoy people. I just googled a bit and found you an answer. Also, please stop using chat-abbreviations. "Can you please help" is not too long to be spelled out. Also, you asked "hi, can you pls help?" What makes you think that posting about the same 20 minutes later will yield you an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look here: http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/IntroductionToDBus/

From what it looks like you need to write a file "*.service" that describes the service.

(Quoted from the website)

```
# (Lines starting with hash marks are comments)

# Fixed section header (do not change):
[D-BUS Service]
Names=com.bigmoneybank.Deposits;com.bigmoneybank.Withdrawals
Exec=/usr/local/bin/bankcounter
```

This is what I found within 5 minutes of Googleing.